# I want to vote on questions in the Close Votes review queue

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I would like to vote on a question while reviewing close votes.

I can already edit the question and add a comment from the same page. Is there a particular reason for the vote functionality being hidden in that view?

Comment: this has come up on the main SE meta in the past: [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140405/254079) and [Up/down voting on questions in the close votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211641/254079)

Comment: Just pop the question open in a new tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Self-answering this based on a [comment by Nick Alexeev](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/i-want-to-vote-on-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue?noredirect=1#comment14750_6220).*

This is a site-wide decision, and the rationale behind it is explained in the answers to two StackExchange meta questions:

- [Up/down voting on questions in the close votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211641/up-down-voting-on-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue)
- [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

Essentially it boils down to:

> The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it.

and

> You're given a subset of questions (generally skewed toward the worst) without a chance to even read the answers, and may indeed be predisposed to voting when you don't really have a strong opinion on the contents of the post.

Comment: Personally I do not agree with the answers there. They only focus on _downvoting_, something that is mostly redundant in the review queue - if the question is bad, I just vote to close. What I typically want to do is to _upvote_ questions that have been incorrectly flagged. My opinions in the matter is however not related to this particular question, and is a fight I have to take with the main site.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close are orthogonal.  You vote to close when the question doesn't fit the site, regardless of how well written or presented it is.  You downvote when sloppily written, as just one example.  A question can be sloppy but still on topic, although if really sloppy I refuse to read it and then vote to close for *unclear*.  Often bad question are deserving of both, so it's not always obvious the two are for different reasons.